# How to edit markdown cell in jupyter-notebook ( Could not edit markdown cell in Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I got a strange problem with `jupyter-notebook`.
I was practicing with `notebook` which has markdown and code cells.

When I save and reopen the notebook, I can edit code cells but not the
markdown cells.

Attempts:

1. reload the page.
2. Make the notebook trusted.
3. Try to change the cell type from markdown to code or raw but still can not edit.

NOTE:
I can delete some letters on markdown but I can not add any letters.
Also if I hit enter it will create new lines, but I can not write anything there.

**Question**
How can we edit the markdown cell of a `jupyter-notebook` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In case anybody also encountered the same problem, I am keeping this question
and my solution to it, instead of deleting the question.

What I did is :
a) First go to markdown cell.
b) Double click the cell, now we can only delete the letters, can not edit it.
c) Go to command mode (press esc) and again come back to edit mode (Enter).
d) Now we can edit the markdown cell.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Double click on cell is enough for me. Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], IPython 6.1.0.

Comment: I have the same problem (in jupyter-lab), but this solution doesn’t work for me. Sadly, no amount of double-clicking, escaping, entering in any permutation works for me.

Comment: Python 3.8.10 in WSL2 and running jupyter notebook in web browser: a double click is enough to edit a markdown cell, to see output, you have to click 'Run' command in selected cell, and escape key is not assigned by default to switch to command mode.

Answer (score 12):

Just double click on the markdown cell. Edit what you want to and Run. It will reflect the changes. Save your notebook.